# Correcting printed PCB (add a via)

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly, via, pcb-layers

This board is a prototype for the project and is for testing. It is missing the soldermask and silkscreen layers, so correcting mistakes is very possible. The board was printed correctly, but somehow I missed one via (grr) from the top layer of copper to the bottom, and the software I used (ExpressPCB) of course doesn't have any checks for things like this.

I would like to know how to add my own via. There is no ground plane on this board because I used the bottom layer for traces to lower the size of the board. It is a basic 2 layer "prototype PCB".

Below you can find a picture of the portion of the board front and back with the trace ends circled. They are lined up **directly** over/under each other. I need to connect those two.

**Top**
[image]

**Bottom**

[image]

The two solutions I'd imagine would work:

1. Use a tiny drill bit or mill and drill a hole through, and make sure solder is filling the whole and touching both traces
2. Just solder a wire to the top trace, wrap it around, and solder it to the bottom trace.

Answer (score 13):

I suggest you combine the two methods. Drill a hole near the traces and thread a thin bare wire through the board, lay it **along** the exposed traces by a few mm and solder it on both sides.

If you don't have such a wire handy, just strip a piece of stranded wire and use one of the strands

Nobody will notice unless they look very carefully, and it will be reliable.

Comment: I'd agree with that - don't disturb the existing copper trace - just solder to it. But, why oh why no earth plane?

Comment: @Andyaka I wonder what software it was.. I think I'd have to try hard to miss a via with Altium (it would fail DRC for sure) and I'm sure Eagle is equally competent when it comes to connectivity DRC. I do like polygon pour of ground and power.. with a little stitching you can almost get a 4-layer board effect with two layers.

Comment: He might have used a mech eng package hence no thoughts about an earth plane!! I'd use Altium if I had the choice but I have to use mentalgraphics absurdity called PADs.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, no sure why I didn't think of that. @SpehroPefhany this is ExpressPCB which is annoying proprietary software that doesn't let you import or export to or from anything. This is for school, so I'm using the software since the school pays -_-. As for why no ground plane, I wanted to cram this into as small area as possible and ended up using the second layer of copper for traces, so I just ran fat ground traces, as this is for prototyping & testing.

Comment: The final board is already in Eagle/KiCad and hopefully will be fabbed nicely with ground plane and all :)

Comment: I would use wire-wrap wire (30 gauge) to connect the traces.

Comment: @Andyaka You only think PADS is 'interesting', for the full mentalgraphics experience, I give you DxDesigner, which is a complete steaming pile. Have you discovered the 'wonderful' PADS DRC 'feature' where it only runs DRC on whatever bit of the board is visible on screen.... I concur that drill a hole nearby, add thin wire-wrap or tinned copper wire and solder along the traces is the way to go. Always worth owning a few reels of wirewrap in different colours, we tend to call it roach wire around here (Because there is seldom just one).

Comment: @DanMills I totally freaking agree DxD is the most awful piece of shit that could ever masquerade as anything remotely useful. Glad to meet a fellow ex (and hopefully ex) user of this turd ridden excuse for vomit. Btw I used it for ten months and asked to be sacked if they disagreed with me. They agreed!